# Why in spite of installing tensorflow I couldn't import it

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used `pip install tensorflow` and it is installed but when I import it in spyder I get no module name tensorflow.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that didn't work. What else should I try?

Comment: Are you sure that it installed in the correct location?

Comment: how many python installations? do you use the same interpreter in spyder where tensorflow is installed?